# overwriting external hive tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

External tables in hive cannot be deleted. Then how can we overwrite it?

Is overwrting hive  tables possible , when we cant drop them?

Comment: Not familiar with HIVE, but likely there could be something like FOREIGN Table keys that keep other tables from being deleted because they depend on links, or other such situations that can keep you from deleting a table.  

If its anything like MySQL you can use UPDATE tablename SET foo = bar to update the data, although you might want to add WHERE this = that to the end to make sure you get the exact row of data and not set ALL the data to that.

Comment: are you getting any error. where you see deleting External tables in hive is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course its possible.
Pls note `external` tables are actually hdfs tables but not owned or managed by hive. Hive metastore stores only the schema metadata of the external table. Hive does not manage, or restrict access, to the actual external data. So, you can overwrite it but you're not the owner of the table. Even if you drop the table using hive, only metadata gets removed and physical data exists in external storage.

Below pic will give you more idea about how hive handles external tables.
[pic](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/using-hiveql/content/hive_create_an_external_table.html)
[image]